# What laws do crypto exchanges need to abide by?

Tags: cryptocurrency

So they need to collect personal information on each user most of the time right?

But how thorough does this information need to be?

Do the exchanges need to check with each government to make sure the information is valid? Or is submitting documents enough?

Comment: Under which country's laws? Different countries can impose different rules.

Answer (score 4):

> Do the exchanges need to check with each government to make sure the information is valid? Or is submitting documents enough?

They need to understand the (usually very complicated) laws governing financial services and data protection in every jurisdiction where they operate.  The specific requirements will vary from one jurisdiction to the next.

The usual way of acquiring this understanding is to hire a lawyer (or several).

Comment: Also they are considered to "operate" in every country they have a customer. So a company in France with customers in Germany and the UK is considered to be operating in all three.